# How to search "Polish" text from SQL Server using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have to search a Polish text from SQL database in my windows application. In the SQL Database, the field is in Polish language.

Eg: The DB fields are Id, Name and values are 1 , Ąćłń.
I have a textbox for entering searching text. When I enter the textbox value "Ąćłń", now the result is empty. The select query is working fine with English characters. My question is how can I search a Polish text?

Comment: Parameter `Varchar` or `NVarchar`?

Comment: "Ąćłń", whether you already stored with this type of character in Database ?

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried so far? Thank you.

Comment: If you are trying something like this: `SELECT  Id 
FROM <table_name>
WHERE  Name = 'Ąćłń'` then please try changing it to `SELECT  Id 
FROM <table_name>
WHERE  Name = N'Ąćłń'` .. Thank you.

Comment: @BAdmin: better yet - convert it to a **parametrized query** to avoid SQL injection attacks!

Answer (score 0):

This should not be any different than searching English or any other language text....

1. connect to your database
2. fire off a **parametrized** search query, making sure to use `nvarchar` as your parameter type
3. show the results!

So basically, something a bit like:

```
    public List<object> Search(string searchArgument)
    {
        string searchQry = "SELECT (list of columns) FROM dbo.YourTableName WHERE Name = @SearchArg;";

        // Define connection and command to use
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("....."))
        using (SqlCommand cmdSearch = new SqlCommand(searchQry, conn))
        {
            // add parameter to search command - make sure to define NVarChar and a valid length!
            cmdSearch.Parameters.Add("@SearchArg", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

            // set parameter value
            cmdSearch.Parameters["@SearchArg"].Value = searchArgument;

            // open connection, execute query, handle results
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdSearch.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // loop over rows returned
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    // do something with results - create your objects that you want to return...

                }

                // close reader 
                rdr.Close();
            }

            // close connection
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

And using an OR Mapper like Entity Framework would make this even easier still.

Answer (score 0):

- [**Alter fulltext catalog CATALOGNAME
  REBUILD WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY=OFF;**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlfts/archive/2010/12/11/part2-sql-full-text-search-and-international-characters-interesting-scenarios-solutions-and-deep-dive-using-dmv-s.aspx)
- Or specify an accent-sensitive collation in the query. For example:

  ```
  select * 
  from users 
  where name like 'HELEN%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
  ```

  - **If you don't have fulltext catalog** (which you should) you can configure the database so that it is accent-sensitive; change the collation to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI.

Options 1 and 2 are simplest from a database administrator's perspective

Option 3 is simplest from a programmer's perspective

Other collation related tips

- Version of SQL Server via `Select @@Version`
- SQL Server collation via `SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));`
- Table datatype definition of your Polish text (i.e. Nvarchar or varchar)
- The ideal polish Collation is case insensitive **SQL_Polish_Cp1250_CI_AS_KI_WI**
- Patch your SQL Server to the most recent level
- Default SQL Server collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
- [Review this Article](https://www.insitesystems.com/services/articles/accent-sensitivity-in-sql-server.html)

WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = {ON|OFF}

Specifies if the catalog to be altered is accent-sensitive or accent-insensitive for full-text indexing and querying.

Notice here:

```
select * from member where name like 'müller' COLLATE German_PhoneBook_CI_AI
```

it will find "müller", "mueller", and "Müller"

and

```
SELECT * FROM mytest WHERE SOUNDEX (col1 )=SOUNDEX ('Muller')
```

it will find "müller", "mueller", and "Müller"

Comment: Since the column is of type `NVARCHAR`, these collations really don't mean anything - `NVARCHAR` is a 2-byte-per-character Unicode character anyway....